# change date time format using webconfig

Tags: asp.net, date, datetime, web-config

I'm trying to change date time format for all my asp.net application using webconfig file

I'm using this code

```
<globalization enableClientBasedCulture="false" uiCulture="es" culture="es-MX" />
```

and the date time appears like this
" 26/10/2013 07:10:50 p.m.  "

how can i change the format to something like this
"dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss a", this is example
"26/10/2013 07:10:50 PM"

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem using the following code

```
<globalization enableClientBasedCulture="false" uiCulture="en-AU" culture="en-AU" />
```